# Is it possible to use 'fs' (filesystem) module inside page executed by PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, phantomjs, teaspoon, filesystem-access

I want to have access to filesystem on a page that is rendering by PhantomJS headless browser.

I catch an error when JS code is trying to interact with filesystem

```
var fs = require('fs');
...
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

Is there some hack/plugin to PhantomJS that allows to do that?

P.S. I'm using headless tests runner based on PhantomJS ([teaspoon](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon)) and I want to store some data from tests on filesystem.

Comment: I have no idea how teaspoon works, but I doubt that it has access to the PhantomJS context. The most probable answer is **no**.

Comment: My hope is based on fact that PhantomJS isn't browser for users, but for testing. So may be there are some opportunities to extend it functionality in a way traditional browsers aren't extendable to.

Comment: Sure, PhantomJS is extensible and it can do this sort of thing. It's a limitation of the tools that build on top of it.